# HP Pavilion P257NL Overheating

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, hp, bumblebee, overheating

I'd like to dual boot my HP Pavilion 15 P257NL with Windows 7.

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but it was getting very hot (only on Ubuntu, it stayed cool in Windows 7). I tried Googling, and I found `bumblebee` and some other programs such as `thermaid` but they didn't solve the problem. So I updated to Ubuntu 15.10. The heating problem was still there, although reduced a bit. Then, I tried another distro (Fedora 23) but it didn't help at all. I read online that this is likely to be caused by the dual video card, so here's my PC configuration:

```
Intel Core i7-5500U
Intel HD Graphics 5500
NVIDIA GeForce 840M
```

I know that there are a lot of questions about this problem but none of the answers solved my problem. I've been struggling with this for three weeks.

**EDIT**

Here are some screenshots with psensor.

This is the computer just started and doing nothing:
[image]

Here's what happens as soon as I open Firefox and play a video on Youtube:
[image]

**On Windows I get an average temperature of 40°C while in a Skype call with Youtube and lots of open tabs on Chrome**, so I don't get how the temperature can be so high on Ubuntu. Needless to say, the fan is almost always on.

**EDIT 2**

As Android Dev asked me, here are the Nvidia X Server settings screenshots after playing a video on Youtube for about 3 minutes:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I did a stress test with Prime95 but I had to kill it after only 5 minutes because the temperature was rising very quickly. Here's the temperatures after that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{FYI - I'll clean this up after we figure out what exactly is going on}

Please install Psesnor

1) `sudo apt-get update`

2) `sudo apt-get install psensor`

Please report back with the temperatures it shows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the screenshots. If you need more details, feel free to ask. Thank you again.

Comment: @Aurasphere -  From the spec sheets, you have an Intel Core i7-5500U, correct? Also, are you using the default open-source graphics driver, or are you using the proprietary Nvidia driver?

Comment: Yes, that's my processor and I'm using Nvidia proprietary driver.

Comment: @Aurasphere - Please take screenshots of two pages in the Nvidia Settings; see my above for the correct ones.

Comment: I've updated the question with the screenshots you asked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Aurasphere - Well, it certainly isn't overheating. The CPU and GPU temps are both WELL within their limits. **However**, could you run Prime 95 on all cores for 15 minutes and report the CPU temps? Watch them closely. **Kill it if they go over 87 degrees.**

Comment: I've added the results of the tests. I had to kill it before the end because the temperature was very high...

Comment: @Aurasphere - Have you tried updating the BIOS?

Comment: I thought about it. The problem is that this computer used to have Windows 8 with UEFI and I've installed Windows 7 MBR with Ubuntu. Since that, the HP support assistant had problems downloading the BIOS update (only this specific update). I can still download it manually, but I'm a bit scared that something could go wrong during the installation and make serious damages. This would be a problem since I use this pc at work and is a very good one. Do you think there would be another solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Aurasphere - Always update the BIOS manually. I'd never trust HP's tool to do it for me. True, it could brick during flashing, but the risk is small. I can't really help you any further, so I'd suggest putting a bounty on this question so that the experts will notice it, and maybe they could shed some light on the issue.